# Can I use async function in Node.js to replace the role of worker in worker queue pattern?

Tags: node.js, architecture

We are planning to rewrite an existing system from sync programming language to Node.js. For this system, we have been using work queue for writing data into database. (run a daemon as worker to get a message from message queue (Redis) and write the message to persistent storage database)

The question is - Can I use async function in Node.js to replace the role of worker in worker queue pattern?

Comment: Yes, you can use async operations for that.  All database access via node.js is generally done asynchronously.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. For the performance points of view, is it a good choice by using async operation?

Comment: Yes, that is the general concept behind node.js.  The server itself runs a single threaded JS event loop, but it gets great scalability because the server is never waiting on I/O because all I/O is done with async operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use async operations for that. All database access via node.js is generally done asynchronously.